# Create Bit Array for negative number in java

Tags: java, negative-number

Given a number, I need to create a bit array. `value` and `width` of the number are known. For positive number i did like this:

```
int[] createbitarr(int value, int width)
{
    int _val = value;
    int bitarr[]=new int[width];
    for (int i=0;value>0;i++)
    {
    bitarr[bitarr.length-i-1]=value%2;
    value=value/2;
    }
    value=_val;
    return bitarr;
}
```

This will work only if the value is positive. How can i create a bit array if value is negative?

Comment: Do you understand two's complement representation? Why are you reinventing the wheel instead of using, say, [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)? What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MattBall I do understand 2's complement representation. I want to get the bit array of 2's complement form only if value is negative. The problem is to create bit array without using any built in library

Comment: @user: why can't you use a built-in library? Is this homework? You should add the 'homework' tag and explain that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *simplest* way would be something like

```
int x; // value 
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
  array[i] = (x & (1 << i)) != 0;
```

Comment: @user - yes it is, and so is the left side ... if I correctly understand what Louis is saying.